# Why does Axios (with async/await) return a full promise?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, axios

I have a problem with `async`/`await`. Here is my code:

```js
import axios from 'axios'

export default async function getRequestedData (requestAddress, params) {
   return await axios.get(requestAddress, {params: params})
}
```

But instead of the result it returns a full promise, so the data is heavily nested inside a promise:

[image]

Comment: A client to get the requested data must invoke the `async` function so s/he has to await for the response
`async func() { 
    [...]
    const data = await getRequestedData(requestAddress, params);
    // processing 'data' - js object ....
}`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Like Ha Ja said, I think you still need to resolve the promise.  If you just return the await you're going to get a promise.

```
const fs = require ('fs')

function getText () {

    return new Promise( (resolve, reject) => {

        fs.readFile('./foo.txt', 'utf8', (err, data) => {
            if (err) {
                reject(err)
            }
                resolve(data)
            })
        })
}

async function output () {
    try {
        let result = await getText()
        console.log("inside try: ", result)
        return result
    }
    catch (err){
        console.log(err)
    }
}

console.log("outside: ", output())
output().then( result => console.log("after then: ", result))

// outside:  Promise { <pending> }
// inside try:  foo text
// inside try:  foo text
// after then:  foo text
```

Answer (score 3):

You have to return the data:

```
const response = await axios.get(requestAddress, {params: params})
return response.data;
```

Comment: Still a Promise but with diffrence [[PromiseValue]] has only content of data object

Comment: How about ```return await axios.get(requestAddress, {params: params}).then(response => response.data)``` ?

Comment: The same result as the last one

Comment: Could you share how you called the function ```getRequestedData```?

Comment: This is a great response .. what does it look like, taking into account the reject block (I mean `catch`)?

Comment: @robertotomás put those 2 lines inside a try block
`try { let response = await axios.get(API_URL, API_PARAMS); return response.data; } catch (error) { console.log(error); }`

Answer (score 2):

One liner:

```
return (await axios.get(url)).data;
```

Answer (score 0):

In React component you can do with this trick:

```
function InitProduct() {
    // Get your product from database
    var productId = 'abc';
    axios.get('/api/products/' + productId).then(response => {
        $('.' + productId).text(response.data.ProductTitle);
    });

    return (<div className={productId}></div>)
}

export class TestNow extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                {InitProduct()}
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

An async function will always wrap what it returns in a promise so you should chain the caller with a `then()` method thereby resolving that promise for example:
getRequestedData (requestAddress, params).then (
(data) => {
...do something...
});

Or you could `await` the call to `getRequestedData` `function`, in which case the data inside the returned promise would be extracted for example:

```
let requestedData = await getRequestedData (requestAddress, params):
```